# Prove that lim $\int_{E_n}f d\mu = 0$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Well they give me the following statement:

> Be $f$ integrable in $(X,F,\mu)$ and {$E_n$} $\subset F$ as {$E_n$} $ \downarrow E$ with $\mu(E) = 0$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n} f d\mu = 0$

Well my idea to prove this is use the DCT (Dominated Convergence Theorem) as $f*\mathbb{1_{E_n}} \rightarrow f*\mathbb{1_{E}}$ and |$f*\mathbb{1_{E_n}}$| $< f$ I use the DCT and:

$\lim \int_{E_n} f d\mu = \lim \int f*\mathbb{1_{E_n}} d\mu = \int_{X} \lim f*\mathbb{1_{E_n}} d\mu = \int_{X} f*\mathbb{1_{E}} d\mu = f*\mu(E) = 0$

I don't know if this is correct or not.

Comment: What is $\color{yellow}{f(E)} * \mu(E)$?

Comment: The symbol $*$ is often used for convolution, perhaps $\cdot$ might be a better choice?

Comment: The last step is not correct. It is true that $\int_X f \cdot 1_E d \mu = 0$ but that does not equal $f \cdot \mu(E)$, which is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X,\mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f$ be nonnegative and integrable. For every $E \in \mathcal F$, define a new measure $\nu$ by $$\nu(E) = \int_E f\,d\mu$$
In your case, since $(E_n) \downarrow E$, so $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$, under the hypothesis that one of the $E_n$ has finite measure, thanks to the continuity from above of $\nu$ we have

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{E_n} f d\mu = \lim_{n\to \infty} \nu(E_n) = \nu\left(\bigcap_nE_n \right) = \nu(E) = \int_E f d\mu = 0$$

Comment: Note that $\nu$ is a **signed** measure.

Comment: And what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well, I made a mistake, in the above $\nu$ is **not** a signed measure. You have assumed that $f\ge 0 $ and that one of the $E_n$ have finite measure. Neither assumption is necessary.

Comment: Well, to use continuity from above you $\textbf{need}$ that at least one of the $E_n$ has finite measure.. think about $E_n := [n,\infty) $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.. But this is obviously satisfied since otherwise it would be impossible that they converge to a set of null measure. While for the question about $f\ge 0$ it is not really useful, if $f$ is not always positive consider separately $f_+$ and $f_{-}$ (positive and negative parts of $f$).

Comment: It is quite possible that $\mu E_n = \infty$ for all $n$. However $\nu$ is **always** finite. You do not need to make that assumption.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on $\nu$, but please, show me an example of sets $E_n$ and a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(E_n) =\infty$ for all $n$ and they converge from above to a set $E$ with $\mu(E) = 0$.

Comment: The example you gave above is the standard example with the Lebesgue measure. The question does not require that $\mu E_n \to 0$, just that $\mu E = 0$. However, it is irrelevant.

Comment: In fact in my answer I did not use that $\mu(E_n) \to 0$, as well I did not mention it in the question i asked you before.. I simply think that it's wrong to say "it is quite possible that all $E_n$ have $\mu(E_n) = \infty$"

Comment: I'm not sure why you are arguing this. Take any integrable $f$ on the real line and $E_n = [n,\infty)$. Then $E_n \downarrow \emptyset$, $mE_n = \infty$ and $\int_{E_n} f \to 0$.

Comment: My point was that your answer has two unnecessary assumptions.

Comment: Oh, well, blind me ahah.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda A = \int_A |f| d \mu$. Then $\lambda$ is a finite measure since $f$ is integrable. In particular, it is continuous from above, so $
\lambda E_n \downarrow \lambda E = 0$. Since $\lambda E_n \ge |\int_{E_n} f d \mu| \ge 0$ we see that
$\int_{E_n} f d \mu  \to 0$.